# Auto categorize questions (Placeholder)

Tags: script, placeholder, python

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

I am just starting to write the code. Will update as I make progress. My plan is as following:

1. Scrape about 50 questions and answers per tag from select set of websites.
2. Train a neural network and use a n-gram model to predict the tags

### About

Trying to write a script that can predict the tags and the stack exchange site. [I am just starting to develop this, so its not ready for prime time] This is a place holder.

#### License

Not decided on the license. Most likely will be free for non-commercial use. As I said not decided.

#### Download

None at the moment.

#### Platform

Ubuntu and OS X using Python.

### Code

Using Python and Keras